# How to split a string from a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to be able to split a string from a repeating pattern. For exemple:
`id||eq||2,id||eq||1`
will give me `id||eq||2` and `id||eq||1`

this is easy because the separator is `,`. But unfortunately I can have the separator inside the splitted part:

```
id||eq||2,2,id||eq||1
```

and I would like to get `id||eq||2,2` and `id||eq||1`

I tried something like this: `(\w+\|{2}\w+\|{2}[\w,]+,?)`

But it always take the first part of the next group and not the second group
`id||eq||1,2,id||eq||2,1`

I'm out of ideas, if some of you can help me ?

**EDIT**

To be more precise, I want to get an array of objects (lets call it RequestFilter[]) from an url (and the param in the url is already an array).

An object RequestFilter looks like this:

- `field`which is a string and can only contain alphanumeric chars
- `type` which is an enum, can either contain only alphanumeric chars
- `filter` which can be any char ( like `,`)

which give me this in the url:
?filter[]=field||type||filter

today I already get `RequestFilter` from an url, but now I have to get an array of `RequestFilter`. I could use any separator, but because the attribute `filter` can be anything there will always be a risk of conflict with it while splitting.

some more examples of strings I can have and the expected RequestFilter[]:

- `name||cont||pier`

```
[{field: 'name', type: 'cont', filter: 'pier'}]
```

---

- `name||cont||a,id||in||2,3`

```
[{field: 'name', type: 'cont', filter: 'pier'},{field: 'id', type: 'in', filter: '2,3'}]
```

---

- `id||in||2,3,4,5,address||eq||Paris,France`

```
[{field: 'id', type: 'in', filter: '2,3,4,5'},{field: 'address', type: 'eq', filter: 'Paris,France'}]
```

**EDIT 2**

I was pretty sure it was possible to handle it with Regex but if you think it's not possible just tell me and I will try to find another way to handle it.

Comment: You should go back to your data source and fix it.  This is the best thing to do.

Comment: Will need some more detail about the rules - how is it supposed to know that the second 2 goes on the first part and not at the start of the second part?

Comment: `s.split(/,(?=\w+\|\|)/)`?

Comment: Can you try to explain your rules a bit better - when do you want to split on a comma, and when do you want to keep it?   How complex can the rest of it get, as at the moment it looks like you would be best to widen your matches, to try and pick up the whole of  id||eq||xxx

Comment: Guessing game is on, please precise the question if you want a *relevant* answer that will *help* you. Or you will have a ton of answers and you will spend a lot of time checking if anything works for you.

Comment: The `filter` field can only have one `,` ?

Answer (score 2):

A solution using **Negative lookahead assertion**:

```js
const str = 'id||eq||2,id||eq||1';
const str2 = 'id||eq||2,2,id||eq||1';

console.log(
  str.split(/(?!,\d),/)
)

console.log(
  str2.split(/(?!,\d),/)
)
```

Comment: loved this solution

Comment: it's too permissive (I edited the question to be more clear), but it's a good way to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
str = 'id||eq||2,2,id||eq||1'
splitted = str.split('id||eq||')
splitted.forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
    arr[index]= 'id||eq||'+item;
})
splitted.shift()

console.log(splitted)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split it by ',id' and then do some manipulations like below

```js
let str='id||eq||2,2,id||eq||1'
//split by ',id'
let arr=str.split(',id');
//join with fixed pattern
let result=arr.join('___id');
//split with fix pattern again
let final_arr=result.split('___');

console.log(final_arr);
```